# Why Stored Procedure Stage error while it works fine on CLI?

Tags: oracle, etl, data-warehouse, datastage

I have a Stored Procedure, i've already tried my Stored Procedure with Begin StoredProcedureName; End;
In My CLI and it's a success. My Stored Procedure works absolutely fine and perfect.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SCHEMA"."TEST_SP"
IS
    BACKDATE_BUSSDATE DATE;
    VAR VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN

    --- SET VARIABLE END OF MONTH ---
    SELECT EOMLASTMONTH 
    INTO BACKDATE_BUSSDATE
    FROM DIM_DATE WHERE TO_DATE(BUS_DT,'DD/MM/YYYY') = TO_DATE(SYSDATE-1,'DD/MM/YYYY');

    -- TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP
    VAR := 'TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP_INSERT_BACKDATE_HIPORT';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE VAR;

    --- INSERT DATA KE TEMP TABLE YG DI BUAT ---
    INSERT INTO TEMP_INSERT_BACKDATE_HIPORT
    SELECT CURR.BUSINESS_NUMBER,CURR.PERSON_NUMBER,CURR.ACCOUNT_SOURCE,CURR.PRODUCT_CODE,CURR.CONTAINER_NUMBER,CURR.CURRENCY_CODE,CURR.EXCHANGE_RATE,CURR.QUANTITY,CURR.MARKET_PRICE,CURR.MARKET_PRICE_DATE,CURR.PURCHASE_PRICE,CURR.PURCHASE_VALUE,CURR.CURRENT_BALANCE_ORG_AMOUNT,CURR.CURRENT_BALANCE_IDR_AMOUNT,CURR.TOTAL_DEBIT_AMOUNT,CURR.TOTAL_CREDIT_AMOUNT,CURR.LAST_MONTH_BALANCE_ORG_AMOUNT,CURR.PROFIT_LOSS_POTENTIAL_PCT,CURR.SUM_INSURED_AMOUNT,CURR.CASH_BLOCKING_FLAG,CURR.CASH_BLOCKING_REASON,CURR.INTEREST_RATE,CURR.INTEREST_TYPE_CODE,CURR.ACCRUED_INTEREST,CURR.PAYMENT_DATE,CURR.PROCESS
    FROM (SELECT * FROM TEST
    WHERE ACCOUNT_SOURCE = 'HIPORT' 
    AND BUSINESS_DATE = TO_DATE(SYSDATE-1,'DD/MM/YYYY')) CURR
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM TEST
    WHERE ACCOUNT_SOURCE = 'HIPORT' 
    AND TO_DATE(BUSINESS_DATE) = TO_DATE(SYSDATE-2)) EOM
    ON EOM.BUSINESS_NUMBER = CURR.BUSINESS_NUMBER 
    AND EOM.PERSON_NUMBER = CURR.PERSON_NUMBER 
    AND EOM.ACCOUNT_SOURCE = CURR.ACCOUNT_SOURCE 
    AND EOM.PRODUCT_CODE = CURR.PRODUCT_CODE
    WHERE EOM.BUSINESS_NUMBER IS NULL;

    --- INSERT DATA KE FACT WM POSITION DARI TEMP TABLE ---
    LOOP
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(BACKDATE_BUSSDATE);
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'INSERT INTO TEST(BUSINESS_DATE,BUSINESS_NUMBER,PERSON_NUMBER,ACCOUNT_SOURCE,PRODUCT_CODE,CONTAINER_NUMBER,CURRENCY_CODE,EXCHANGE_RATE,QUANTITY,MARKET_PRICE,MARKET_PRICE_DATE,PURCHASE_PRICE,PURCHASE_VALUE,CURRENT_BALANCE_ORG_AMOUNT,CURRENT_BALANCE_IDR_AMOUNT,TOTAL_DEBIT_AMOUNT,TOTAL_CREDIT_AMOUNT,LAST_MONTH_BALANCE_ORG_AMOUNT,PROFIT_LOSS_POTENTIAL_PCT,SUM_INSURED_AMOUNT,CASH_BLOCKING_FLAG,CASH_BLOCKING_REASON,INTEREST_RATE,INTEREST_TYPE_CODE,ACCRUED_INTEREST,PAYMENT_DATE,PROCESS_NAME,INSERT_DATE)'
                            || 'SELECT TO_DATE('''|| BACKDATE_BUSSDATE || ''',''DD-MM-YYYY''),BUSINESS_NUMBER,PERSON_NUMBER,ACCOUNT_SOURCE,PRODUCT_CODE,CONTAINER_NUMBER,CURRENCY_CODE,EXCHANGE_RATE,QUANTITY,MARKET_PRICE,MARKET_PRICE_DATE,PURCHASE_PRICE,PURCHASE_VALUE,CURRENT_BALANCE_ORG_AMOUNT,CURRENT_BALANCE_IDR_AMOUNT,TOTAL_DEBIT_AMOUNT,TOTAL_CREDIT_AMOUNT,LAST_MONTH_BALANCE_ORG_AMOUNT,PROFIT_LOSS_POTENTIAL_PCT,SUM_INSURED_AMOUNT,CASH_BLOCKING_FLAG,CASH_BLOCKING_REASON,INTEREST_RATE,INTEREST_TYPE_CODE,ACCRUED_INTEREST,PAYMENT_DATE,PROCESS,TO_DATE(SYSDATE)'
                             || 'FROM TEMP_INSERT');
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'INSERT INTO TEST (BUSINESS_DATE,BUSINESS_NUMBER,PERSON_NUMBER,ACCOUNT_SOURCE,PRODUCT_CODE,CONTAINER_NUMBER,CURRENCY_CODE,EXCHANGE_RATE,QUANTITY,MARKET_PRICE,MARKET_PRICE_DATE,PURCHASE_PRICE,PURCHASE_VALUE,CURRENT_BALANCE_ORG_AMOUNT,CURRENT_BALANCE_IDR_AMOUNT,TOTAL_DEBIT_AMOUNT,TOTAL_CREDIT_AMOUNT,LAST_MONTH_BALANCE_ORG_AMOUNT,PROFIT_LOSS_POTENTIAL_PCT,SUM_INSURED_AMOUNT,CASH_BLOCKING_FLAG,CASH_BLOCKING_REASON,INTEREST_RATE,INTEREST_TYPE_CODE,ACCRUED_INTEREST,PAYMENT_DATE,PROCESS_NAME,INSERT_DATE)'
                            || 'SELECT TO_DATE('''|| BACKDATE_BUSSDATE || ''',''DD-MM-YYYY''),BUSINESS__NUMBER,PERSON_NUMBER,ACCOUNT_SOURCE,PRODUCT_CODE,CONTAINER_NUMBER,CURRENCY_CODE,EXCHANGE_RATE,QUANTITY,MARKET_PRICE,MARKET_PRICE_DATE,PURCHASE_PRICE,PURCHASE_VALUE,CURRENT_BALANCE_ORG_AMOUNT,CURRENT_BALANCE_IDR_AMOUNT,TOTAL_DEBIT_AMOUNT,TOTAL_CREDIT_AMOUNT,LAST_MONTH_BALANCE_ORG_AMOUNT,PROFIT_LOSS_POTENTIAL_PCT,SUM_INSURED_AMOUNT,CASH_BLOCKING_FLAG,CASH_BLOCKING_REASON,INTEREST_RATE,INTEREST_TYPE_CODE,ACCRUED_INTEREST,PAYMENT_DATE,PROCESS,TO_DATE(SYSDATE)'
                             || 'FROM TEMP_INSERT';
         BACKDATE_BUSSDATE := TO_DATE(BACKDATE_BUSSDATE+1,'DD/MM/YYYY');
         EXIT WHEN TO_DATE(BACKDATE_BUSSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY') = TO_DATE(SYSDATE-1,'DD/MM/YYYY');
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I tried to put my Stored Procedure in Stored Procedure Stage in DataStage.
 My Job Design look like this

```
Oracle Connector=>Transformer=>Oracle Connector=>Stored Procedure
```

With 0 Data the job run perfectly. When i tried with 1 or more data it gave me an error ORA-6512.
Isn't "ORA-xxxx" error from the Oracle error? But i run my Oracle Stored Procedure and it's finished perfectly.

My Stored Procedure Stage configuration looked like this

Syntax : 
Procedure Name : TEST_SP
Procedure Type : Transform
Generate Procedure call : checked (i've tried manually 'unchecked' and still same results)

Data Connection: (Empty)

General : 
I've already fill all the credentials

in Input : 
Execute Procedure for each row (checked)
Columns: i take all from the transformer

Please anyone have any idea? I'm very much already stuck.

Edit : 
This is the message when I change the Stored Procedure Stage into "Target"

Stored_Procedure_5,0: Fatal Error: Fatal: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TEST_SP' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
The Stored Procedure error

and this is the message when I change into transform

Stored_Procedure_5,0: Fatal Error: Fatal: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected ORA-06512: at "SCHEMA.TEST_SP", line 8 ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: please show the complete error stack trace.

Comment: Are you using / designing a paralllel job in DataStage?

Comment: This is the message when I change the Stored Procedure Stage into "Target"
Stored_Procedure_5,0: Fatal Error: Fatal: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TEST_SP' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
The Stored Procedure error 
and this is the message when I change into transform
Stored_Procedure_5,0: Fatal Error: Fatal: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected ORA-06512: at "SCHEMA.TEST_SP", line 8 ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: Yes I'm using in parallel job, with the stored procedure stage in the palette in database tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most likely this:

```
TO_DATE(SYSDATE-1,'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

SYSDATE is already a date, so when we see this this, we do this:

- evaluate SYSDATE-1
- convert that to a string (because TO_DATE takes a string as first input)
- then convert that string to a date with TO_DATE

In *your* session, the default format mask is probably dd/mm/yyyy so the conversion from date to string and then back again works without incident.

In DataStage, if their session format is different (eg DD-MON-YYYY) then you'll get an error because you will do:

- convert sysdate-1 to string = 10-MAY-2020
- try convert that to a date using DD/MM/YYYY..... splat!

The code

```
BUSINESS_DATE = TO_DATE(SYSDATE-1,'DD/MM/YYYY'))
```

just needs to be be

```
BUSINESS_DATE = trunc(SYSDATE-1)
```

Comment: So i tried to move the stored procedure stage after the oracle connector, and after my last transformer.
It gave me a success(green line), when i moved it after the oracle connector, but the Stored Procedure didn't run/execute.
But when i moved the stored procedure stage after my transformer, so my transformer has 2 branches of nodes, the firt to oracle connector, second to stored procedure.
it gave me an error.
and yes i've tried your advice, thankyou for answering btw :)